# Shiny DataTable: Disable row selection for certain rows

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I am trying to determine if it is possible for a `shiny` `DataTable` to have row selection disabled for certain rows.

Using the `selection` parameter of `DT::datatable` I can pre-select rows, determine whether the user selects rows or columns or both, and disable selection entirely, but it isn't clear to me if I can indicate specific rows to exclude. Is this possible?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

With the `Select` extension you can do:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

dat <- iris[1:17,]

rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, data, displayNum, displayIndex){",
  "  var indices = [0, 2, 4, 15];",
  "  if(indices.indexOf(displayIndex) > -1){",
  "    $(row).find('td').addClass('notselectable');",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {    
    output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
      dat %>%
        datatable(options = list(
          rowCallback = JS(rowCallback), 
          select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
        ), 
        extensions = "Select", selection = "none"
        )
    }, server = FALSE)
  }
)
```

But if you need the indices of the selected rows in `input$table_rows_selected`, you have to code in JavaScript for that:

```
callback <- c(
  "var id = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
  "table.on('click', 'tbody', function(){",
  "  setTimeout(function(){",
  "    var indexes = table.rows({selected:true}).indexes();",
  "    var indices = Array(indexes.length);",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i){",
  "      indices[i] = indexes[i];",
  "    }",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue(id + '_rows_selected', indices);",
  "  }, 0);",
  "});"
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {    
    output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
      dat %>%
        datatable(
          callback = JS(callback),
          options = list(
            rowCallback = JS(rowCallback), 
            select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
          ), 
          extensions = "Select", selection = "none"
        )
    }, server = FALSE)
    observe({
      print(input[["table_rows_selected"]])
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution @Stéphane, it really helped me out. I was wondering how I could pass an R vector of row numbers (e.g. `disabled = c(1,2,3)`) to the rowCallback? I am getting by with `paste0("  var indices = ", toJSON(disabled), ";")` but it seems hacky.

Comment: @user51462 You can do `sprintf("  var indices = [%s];", paste0(disabled, collapse = ",")`

Comment: does this still work with column sorting? Say you sort the rows according to `Species` in descending order, then rows 101, 103, 105 and 116 get disabled because their `displayIndex` is now 0, 2, 4 and 15 respectively as a result of the sorting. But what if I wanted to disable rows according to their rownames so that 1, 3, 5 and 16 are always disabled regardless of their `displayIndex`?

Comment: I tried substituting `displayIndex` with `dataIndex` since the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) defines it as "DataTables' internal index for the row" but it doesn't work. I made a post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505250/r-shiny-disabling-specific-rows-in-a-datatable-with-column-sorting), would it please be possible to take a look?

Comment: Great that works. But how can we do it for specific columns?

Comment: I just figured out a solution for columns
```"    $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').addClass('notselectable');",```

Comment: Is this working as intended? Every time something I click something the observe gets two numbers. The first one higher. Selecting the second row give `[1] 2
[1] 1`. An index is off somewhere?

Comment: @JanStanstrup I've just retried and I don't get this behavior. Did you copy my code verbatim?

Comment: Strange. I tried different computers now. With R 3.5.2, shiny_1.3.2 and DT_0.8 I get the expected behavior. On my computer with R 3.6.3,  shiny_1.4.0 and DT_0.13.2 I get this strange double firing.

Comment: @JanStanstrup This is possibly due to a change in `DT` (I'm using 0.10). Could you try to replace `Shiny.setInputValue(id + '_rows_selected', indices)` with `Shiny.setInputValue(id + '_selected_rows', indices)` and do `print(input[["table_selected_rows"]])` in the server code.

Comment: It can now be done with the native selection system (i.e. without the Select extensions and callbacks): https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/793