# R Shiny - Disabling specific rows in a datatable with column sorting

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, datatables, dt

The app below contains a datatable of the `iris` dataset with row selection enabled. I would like to disable selection for the first 3 rows specifically. I can do this using the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551774/10841085). The solution works fine when the table initialises on app startup:

[image]

However, when you sort the rows on a column, e.g. on `Species` in descending order, it disables observations 101, 102 and 103 since they are now the first 3 rows of the table as a result of the sorting:

[image]

I am guessing this happens because `rowCallback` is `displayIndex` to disable rows. So on startup, `displayIndex` 0, 1 and 2 correspond to observations 1, 2 and 3 respectively in the iris dataset and the row callback disables row selection for them since `indices.indexOf(displayIndex) > -1` is `true` for these rows. But after sorting on `Species`, `displayIndex` 0, 1 and 2 correspond to observations 101, 102 and 103 respectively and so the callback disables them instead.

To fix this, I tried disabling rows based on rowname by changing the `displayIndex` in the `rowCallback` function to `dataIndex`. However, this does something weird where additional rows get disabled each time I filter on a different column. Here is an example after the table was first sorted on `Sepal.Length`, then `Sepal.Length` and then finally on `Petal.Length`:

[image]

Here is the code to reproduce the above:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

disabled_rows = c(1,2,3)

#NOTE: displayIndex changed to dataIndex
rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, data, displayNum, dataIndex){",
  sprintf("  var indices = [%s]", toString(disabled_rows - 1)),
  "  if(indices.indexOf(dataIndex) > -1){",
  "    $(row).find('td').addClass('notselectable').css({'background-color': '#eee', 'color': '#bbb'});",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

get_selected_rows <- c(
  "var id = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
  "table.on('click', 'tbody', function(){",
  "  setTimeout(function(){",
  "    var indexes = table.rows({selected:true}).indexes();",
  "    var indices = Array(indexes.length);",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i){",
  "      indices[i] = indexes[i];",
  "    }",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue(id + '_rows_selected', indices);",
  "  }, 0);",
  "});"
)

drag_selection <- c(
  "var dt = table.table().node();",
  "$(dt).selectable({",
  "  distance : 10,",
  "  selecting: function(evt, ui){",
  "    $(this).find('tbody tr').each(function(i){",
  "      if($(this).hasClass('ui-selecting')){",
  "        table.row(i).select();",
  "      }",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "}).on('dblclick', function(){table.rows().deselect();});"
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js")),
    DTOutput('table')
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {  

    output$table <- renderDT({

        datatable(
          iris,
          callback = JS(get_selected_rows),
          class = 'hover row-border order-column',
          options = list(
          rowCallback = JS(rowCallback), 
          select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
          ), 
        extensions = "Select", selection = 'none'
        )
    }, server = F)

    observe({

      print(input$table_rows_selected)

    })
  }
)
```

I don't know why changing `displayIndex` to `dataIndex` isn't working and I don't know what else to try. The DataTables definition of the `dataIndex` parameter [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) is obscure to me since I am not all that familiar with the DT plug-in, so I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** I also tried disabling based on rowname directly as follows:

```
rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, data, displayNum, displayIndex){",
  "  var indices = [0, 2, 4, 15]",
  "  if(indices.indexOf(data[0]) > -1){",
  "    $(row).find('td').addClass('notselectable');",
  "  }",
  "}"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strange that [`dataIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57521490/1100107) does not work.

You can use some id for the rows instead.

```
disabled_rows = paste0("'", paste0("row", c(1,2,3)), "'")

rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, data, displayNum, displayIndex){",
  sprintf("  var indices = [%s];", toString(disabled_rows)),
  "  if(indices.indexOf($(row).attr('id')) > - 1){",
  "    $(row).find('td').addClass('notselectable').css({'background-color': '#eee', 'color': '#bbb'});",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

dat <- iris
dat$ID <- paste0("row", 1:nrow(iris))
rowNames <- TRUE
colIndex <- as.integer(rowNames)


output$table <- renderDT({

  datatable(
    dat,
    rownames = rowNames,
    callback = JS(get_selected_rows),
    class = 'hover row-border order-column',
    options = list(
      rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", 
                         ncol(dat)-1+colIndex)),
      rowCallback = JS(rowCallback), 
      select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
    ), 
    extensions = "Select", selection = 'none'
  )
}, server = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is such a genius workaround, thank you @Stéphane. Would you mind me asking how you knew to use `rowId`? I can't find the documentation for it and would not have realised to use it.

Comment: Thanks, also why is `server = T` required here? I noticed that if I use `server = F`, then I get the same problem as the one I encountered when I substituted `dataIndex` for `displayIndex`.

Comment: @user51462 Mmh weird, I don't see why this causes a difference.

Comment: No worries. Also, the `input$table_selected_rows` returns the `displayIndex` of the selected row rather than its actual index. E.g. if you click on the last observation on page 150, `input$table_selected_rows` returns 9 instead of 149. I tried fixing this by setting the `rowId` to the rownames via `dat$index = rownames(iris)` and then identifying the selected row by its ID using `var indexes = table.rows({selected:true}).attr('id');"` in line 4 of the `get_selected_rows` callback but nothing is returned when a row is selected, would you have any idea as to why?

Comment: Using `dat$index = rownames(iris)` and `"var indexes = table.rows({selected:true}).ids();"` in line 4 of the `get_selected_rows` callback partially fixes it by returning the correct indexes but in character form since they are the row IDs. Is there an `as.numeric` equivalent in JS? I'm still puzzled as to why `rows({selected:true}).index()` and `.indexes()` return the displayIndex. Both methods are supposed to retrieve the internal index according to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()).

Comment: @user51462 [DT has just been updated](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/701). With the development version, [dataIndex](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/699) should work. Use `parseInt` to convert to an integer.