# Internal row index in DataTables rowCallback

Tags: javascript, datatables

The doc of DataTables [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) claims that the fifth argument of the function is the internal row index. However when I use this row callback below, I get `undefined` for `dataIndex`. How to use the internal row index in `rowCallback` ?

```
  function(row, data, displayNum, displayIndex, dataIndex){
    console.log(displayNum); console.log(displayIndex); console.log(dataIndex);
  }
```

Comment: That's weird, if you really need the dataIndex, https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()
Maybe you can try to see all args with `console.log(arguments)`
Maybe the version of datatables can differ

Comment: Mmmm, that's strange. Could you provide all the relevant code? I tried with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pocve5bw/) and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: @mgarcia Thanks for the fiddle. I'm using DataTables through the R package `DT`, not directly in JavaScript. Perhaps it's a bug in `DT`.

Comment: Mmmm, can you provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? If you need npm dependencies, you can use [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: @mgarcia [Here is one](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/699). I've reported this issue. But as I said, this is some R, not directly Javascript. Sounds like a DT bug.