# Shiny DT lock some columns AND rows for editing

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

What I want is that only certain cells are editable by the user,
for example in the iris dataset I want the first 3 rows to be locked and also the second and the third column.

I have found the same question here on SO ([Shiny datatable mode editable - restrict specific columns AND ROWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808485/shiny-datatable-mode-editable-restrict-specific-columns-and-rows)), however unfortunately the provided solution does not work (as there only the columns get locked after running the code). Here is a minimal reprex.

as you can see I wrote both the respective columns and rows in the  argument, however only the columns got locked.

```
library(shiny)

library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

dat <- iris[1:10, ]

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, editable = list(target='cell', disable = list(columns = c(2:3), rows=c(1:3) )))
  }, server = FALSE)
  

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest update of DT, this issue seems to be resolved, now rows and columns can get locked